# android AsyncTask restart error

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am starting an AsyncTask for GPS. It starts fine, but when I try to stop the task and then restart it I get the following error

> java.lang.RuntimeException -> Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

My code i use to restart the task

```
    if (this.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING || 
            this.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.PENDING){
        this.cancel(true);
    }this.execute();
```

Comment: You cannot execute a `AsyncTask` that has been already executed..

Comment: Also the `execute()` needs to be called on the main thread, from the docs - `The AsyncTask class must be loaded on the UI thread. This is done automatically as of JELLY_BEAN.
The task instance must be created on the UI thread.
execute(Params...) must be invoked on the UI thread.`

Answer (score 0):

To extend on what Varun said: Each time you want to run your AsyncTask, you need to create a new instance of your AsyncTask class and execute the new instance.